# Bootsrap: Stacked Progress Bar using an array

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a unique stacked progress bar for every set of time entries.

```
 scope.customDuration = function () {
                        for (var i = 0; i < scope.blocks.length; i++) {
                            var block = scope.blocks[i];
                            if (block.time !== "" && block.time !== null) {
                                blockTimes.push(block.time);
                            }
                        }
                        var duration = blockTimes.join();
                        return duration;
                    }
```

Then, I'd like to make a stacked progress bar with every time as it's own separation. However, I can only figure out to set the total.

```
<div class="progress" style="width: 100%; background-color: #{{type.Color}};">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: {{calculateTotal(type)}}%; background-Color: #{{type.Color}}; color: {{getContrastYIQ(type)}}"> {{type.totalTime}}</div>
                        </div>
```

Is there any way that I can implement customDuration on a progress bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI-Bootstrap comes with directives for bootstrap also including (stacked) progress bars:
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar

Check out this Plunker for an easy to understand example:
http://embed.plnkr.co/PHvMVJd9qdLvTaVnYweg/preview